# Template Composition / Multiple Controllers?

Tags: playframework

I am new to the play framework and I like it a lot, but I do not understand how the following problem can be solved - what would be the right playframework approach?

I am building a complex website with multiple dynamic parts. Let's say a banner, a menu with submenus, a main content part, a sidebar part and a footer. Everthing is dynamic and works on it own, althoug some information is shared among "parts" (like highlighting the selected category in the menu).

For example, the main content part shows a blog article. So the menu should show all categories and the selected category highlighted. The banner and the footer part are not dependend on the main part, so there is no information exchanged.

I think I have to register 5 controllers (banner, menu, main, sidebar, footer) to a url like /blog/article/1 and each controller renders his own section and in the end everything is put together to a complex website.

This also should provide loose coupling between my controllers. The "footer" controller just doesn't have to know there is a "banner" controller.

Please provide any pointers how this is done with playframework 2.x.

Thank you,
Bernhard

Answer (score 2):

The skeleton Play application that you get when you do `play new myapp` is a good start. It gives you `main.scala.html`, which has the `html`, `head` and `body` tags that are common to all pages, and `index.scala.html`, which generates the content within the `body` tag. These two parts of the page are put together by `index.scala.html`, which calls `main()` and passes its own content as a block expression. (`main` is really a singleton view object generated by the Play template parser, and `index` is actually calling `main.apply(title)(content)`).

My approach to generating the navs/menus is approximately as follows:

- My `main.scala.html` function has the signature `@(title:  String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)`
- All the controller actions must now have an implicit request parameter.
- I have a helper object in the `views.html` package (e.g. `views.html.Menus`) with a method similar to `def renderMainMenu()(implicit req: RequestHeader): play.api.templates.Html`. This method generates the menus/submmenus/navs. It looks at `req.uri` to figure out which menu item(s) to highlight, or which breadcrumbs to show.

`main.scala.html` is in fact a layout. If your design has a sidebar and a footer, you could implement these as views, and call them from the appropriate parts of `main`. In terms of your blog example, you would have (for example) an entry `/blog/article/:articleId` in your routes file, an action `controllers.Application.blog(articleId)`, and a view `blog.scala.html` which would generate the content part of the layout.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I did not understand it, since I am a Java developer, not Scala. Should have mentioned it. It seems I need more basic help and that might be too much for stackoverflow. So I posted a request for consulting here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/W-xNKUXhdCI When I get an answer (I understand), I will post it here. Thank you!

Comment: The views in Play framework are in scala, so everything Richard said will be the same if you use Play in Java. The only different part is "I have a helper object in the views.html...." It can be translated to : "I have a helper class with static method public static play.api.templates.html renderMainMenu(RequestHeader header). This method generates the menus/submenus/navs..."

Comment: Other thing, you have to see views as function. So each views are function calls and each view can call other views and passing a body as parameter. So when you create a new application, you see that the index view call the main view with a body.